# How can I lower the resolution of a large amount of stored .JPG files?

Tags: photos

I have a large disk full of folders containing .JPG images, taken with a camera with a high resolution. For data efficiency and streaming purposes, I need to find a way to lower the resolution of the images. I have access to Lightroom and Photoshop and can get any other software if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
magick mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day I used Image Resizer Power tools for Windows XP, doing a Google search I have found this: [ImageResizer](http://www.bricelam.net/ImageResizer/) - which supposedly works for Vista & Win7 and possibly Win10

I am unsure if this will remain a valid answer as I don't own the website and unsure how long the links will remain active for.

Project is maintained by [Brice Lambson](https://github.com/bricelam)

Once installed, all that is required is to select all photos you plan on resizing, right click on one of the photos then click resize pictures.

You get the options to choose what size you would like to resize too and whether or not you want to create a copy of modify the originals.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using only Windows, if you **don't** have a Mail (*Outlook*, for example) program installed

1 - Select all pictures in the folder

2 - *Right-click* on the selected images.

3 - Click on `Send to` and then click on `Mail recipient`.

4 - It will let you select a size for all the images.

5 - Windows will try to open an email program like Outlook. As you don't have one there will be an **error**. Don't click on "OK" and don't close the error message.

6 - Go to the Windows **search** in the Start Menu and type `%temp%` into the search bar.

7 - The Windows **Temp** folder will open and there will be the resized pictures.

8 - Be careful, the images will be along with a bunch of temporary files used by Windows to work. Don't delete or move any of the other files.

9 - Copy them to another directory and click **OK** on the error message